# wordpress, adding a settings action link under my plugin's name for my plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to develop my first plugin for wordpress. I noticed that other plugins I have installed on my wordpress have a link to the plugin setting page right from the plguin page list of plugins.

so right under my plugin's name I see:

> Deactivate

but for some of my other plugins I also see a

> Settings

link that will take the user right to the settings page of that plugin. 
How can I tell wordpress I want such a link for my plugin?

I use this hook to add my settings page:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_admin_add_page');
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the following code to the plugin file.

```
add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'my_plugin_settings' );

function my_plugin_settings( $settings ) {
   $settings[] = '<a href="'. get_admin_url(null, 'settings.php') .'">Settings</a>';
   return $settings;
}
```

Comment: The filter has 2 parameters on the callback: `my_plugin_settings( $links, $file )`. Your admin url is going to a generic page, I normally hardcode the value:`admin_url( 'options-general.php?page=MY-PLUGIN-PAGE' )`.

Comment: The function needs only one parameter. You can hard code the page name.